# Passing data to input form inside cell datatable when checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, datatable

I have a checkbox on a table, where when that checkbox is selected it will pass data in the "sisa" variable. When in the console log , I have managed to display the "sisa" data. But how to submit the "sisa" data in the input form in the next column ("diterima" column). This checkbox is a multiple selection, so you can select many at once.

the screenshoot:
https://i.postimg.cc/qq7CpVrf/error.png

My datatable

```
$('#produkTabel').DataTable({
    "aaData": response.result,
    "columns": [

        {
            "data": "id", "class": "text-center",
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
            }
        },
        {"data": "produk.item_code"},
        {"data": "produk.name"},
        {"data": "jumlah", "class": "text-center"},
        {"data": "sisa", "class": "text-center"},
        {"data": "id", "class": "text-center", render: function ( data,row) {
                return '<input type="number"  id="inputID" class="open-input form-control bg-white" value="0">';
            },},
        {
            "data": "id",
            "class": "text-center",
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
            render: function ( data, type ,row ) {
                if ( type === 'display' ) {
                    return '<input type="checkbox" data-sisa="'+row.sisa+'" class="editor-active">';
                }
                return data;
            },
            className: "dt-body-center"
        },
    ],
    "bDestroy": true,
});
```

My Jquery

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    // var tblData = table.rows('.selected').data();
    let sisa = $(this).data('sisa');
    // console.log(tblData);
    // var inputForm = $(this).'input[type="number"]';
    // $('.open-input').val(sisa);
    // this.checked ? inputForm.val(sisa) : inputForm.val(0);
    console.log(sisa);
});
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, you want to submit "sisa" on this page and transfer value from "sisa" to "diterima" on next page? And you're doing it with PHP and ajax? IF yes you need to do something like this---`&sisa[]=checkbox1&sisa[]=checkbox2` and so on for all the checkbox selected. use a for loop in your jquery to add all values in sisa array

Comment: Thanks @RaoDYC , i want to passing data sisa when checkbox checked into form input "diterima", it already success passing data to console.log(sisa), but i cant figure out how to pass it into input form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#inputID").val(sisa);

Try this in your script....sorry if am wrong